# Overwrite jquery.ui.slider.min.css generated by jQuery Update module

Tags: theming, javascript

The [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module generates a css file `jquery.ui.slider.min.css` for my website. I need to overwrite the `jquery.ui.slider.min.css` for this slider field. I don't want to loose my changes when we update the jQuery Update module.

What is the best way to add jquery.ui.slider.min.css into my theme?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to insert in your themes template.php the following:

```
function mytheme_css_alter(&$css) {
  if (isset($css['misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css'])) {
    $css['sites/default/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/mytheme_jquery_design/jquery.ui.theme.css';
  }
}
```